# Getting the error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 15456: invalid start byte when trying to read a csv file in arabic

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file written in arabic, this is the code i'm using:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/User/Downloads/AJGT.csv",encoding='utf-8')

sentiment = np.array(data.drop('Feed', axis =1).values)
feed = np.array(data.drop('Sentiment', axis =1).values)
print(sentiment)
print(feed)
```

however i'm getting the following error

`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 15456: invalid start byte`

I would appreciate any help
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `encoding='ISO-8859-1'`. This worked for me, as I got similar error.

Comment: Thank you the error is gone however I'm getting '???????????' instead of an arabic text in the output @coco18

Comment: Look in the list of languages, which are supported by the encoding standard